# Map Boundaries! How to check if an address is located in a boundary?

Tags: javascript, css, dictionary, kml, boundary

1. Website user inputs address.
2. If address is inside of boundary, "Eligible". If address is out of boundary, "Ineligible".

Is there an existing widget or code that does this?  Does anybody know the first step to making this happen?  Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 2):

Wow, what's up with the negative votes.  The answer is this .... google maps javascript api v3.  Honestly, why can't people just say that? Yet they'd take the time to -1 the question.  I gotta start somewhere. After googleing terms and phrases for 30 minutes, there was absolutely nothing on it.

I'm going to need to do a combination of the google geocoder and https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/poly-containsLocation.

Thanks for the negative votes!  When I make a killer map script, I'll be sure to post it.